# Saving Textfile to a specific folder using JavaScript on Web

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, text-files

I would like to save my text file on a specific folder/location to store it, what code should I need to use? The code that I have is saving text file that can download using web not saving the file in a specific folder/location since I'm using a OS: Solaris with Tomcat Apache.

Example of Folder/Location:
`/tmp/textFileSaveDir/`

Here my code below:

```
<%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : Mar 7, 2014, 7:33:21 AM
    Author     : Joseph
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table>
    <tr><td>Text to Save:</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <textarea id="inputTextToSave" style="width:512px;height:256px"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Filename to Save As:</td>
        <td><input id="inputFileNameToSaveAs"></input></td>
        <td><button onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Save Text to File</button></td>
        </tr>
</table>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function saveTextAsFile()
{
        <%-- Input Text To Save --%>
    var textToWrite = document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value;
        <%-- Creating file To Save As --%>
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
        <%-- Input Filename To Save As --%>
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;


    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    if (window.webkitURL != null)
    {
        // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
        // without actually adding it to the DOM.
        downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    }
    else
    {
        // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
        // before it can be clicked.
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    }

    downloadLink.click();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `JavaScript` is not made for `File Operations` Use Server side Scripting..

Comment: Also, don't check for vender prefix first, check for non-prefixed first to guarantee future compatible

Answer (score -2):

in my opinion you can use php to store files. Lets say that javascript is the side of the client and php is the side of the server.

so in theory you may use php with some functions like fwrite,fopen and so forth.

thats my opinion

Comment: Actually I have PHP codes created but then I won't create textfile so that I tried to create JavaScript unfortunately still not working.